# Multiply numbers after each other

Tags: numbers, each

Exercise Product1ToN (Loop): Write a program called Product1ToN to compute the product of integers 1 to 10 (i.e., 1×2×3×...×10). Try computing the product from 1 to 11, 1 to 12, 1 to 13 and 1 to 14. Write down the product obtained and explain the results.

How can I do this, and are their multiple ways?

Comment: It would be */ι10 in APL

Comment: ...and what have you done to solve the problem by yourself?

Comment: @ Reinhard. I have tried to find out a way that stores the numbers in each run of a while loop. So each time the while loop runs, the value is added to a variable or something like that. But I have had no success with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private int Product1ToN(int n){
    int result = 1, ctr = 1;

    while(ctr <= n){
        result *= ctr++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please read up on [Java Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) if you need clarification.

Comment: Glad I could help! If it's not much, kindly accept the answer please, thanks :)